# ImageMagick advanced transparency control

Tags: c, imagemagick

I'm trying to put overlay (watermark) on base image. Assuming it looks like this:

[image]

opaque rectangle with "fully transparent" text on it. I.e. all pixels of text is transparent, as well as background under it.

#### 1 way:

I do opacity 60% in Photoshop:

[image]

And just compose it in code:

```
MagickWand* overlay = NewMagickWand();
MagickReadImage(overlay, overlaypath);
MagickCompositeImage(wand, overlay, OverCompositeOp, 100, 100);
//all open/destroy code is omitted
```

And result is rectangle is semi-transparent while text is fully transparent:

[image]

So far so good, but I also wanted to regulate overlay opacity via application config, so I tried second way:

#### 2 way:

100% in Photoshop (as on very first image in this post) and trying to set transparency via MagickWand:

```
MagickReadImage(overlay, overlaypath);
MagickSetImageOpacity(overlay, 0.6);
MagickCompositeImage(wand, overlay, OverCompositeOp, 100, 100);
```

Result is totally blank rectangle, semi-transparent though

[image]

It looks like `MagickSetImageOpacity` set up **every** pixel alpha channel to the same 0.6 value regardless of its current value. What I need is `currentAlpha -= givenAlpha` for every pixel of `overlay` wand. Is this possible without iterate every wand pixel by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to achieve the `currentAlpha -= givenAlpha` would be to invoke a [PixelIterator](http://imagemagick.org/api/pixel-iterator.php#NewPixelIterator), and iterator through each pixel, and apply the givenAlpha with [PixelSetAlpha](http://imagemagick.org/api/pixel-wand.php#PixelSetAlpha). But for you needs, you may be able to apply the same effects with [MagickColorizeImage](http://imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickColorizeImage).

```
PixelWand *pColorize = NewPixelWand();
PixelWand *pGivenAlpha = NewPixelWand();
double userOpacity = 0.6;

// May need to be adjusted to "white" or "black" depending on your mask
PixelSetColor(pColorize, "transparent");
PixelSetAlpha(pGivenAlpha, userOpacity);

MagickWand *overlay = NewMagickWand();
MagickReadImage(overlay, overlaypath);
MagickColorizeImage(overlay, pColorize, pGivenAlpha); // Apply opacity filter
MagickCompositeImage(wand, overlay, OverCompositeOp, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Actually I just completed solution via pixel iterator https://db.tt/IwUcwJ8v basing on [this sample](http://members.shaw.ca/el.supremo/MagickWand/grayscale.htm) and it works. I see that colorize filter could work also, so what's your opinion, what approach is faster/more correct?

Comment: **UPD**: your way also works well. I think I'll try some benhmarks to find out fastest way of this two, but it probably out of my inital question. Thanks.

Comment: Go for the common practice of pixel iteration, it'll give you greater flexibility & reduce tech-dept by not having any business logic hidden behind a "this well work" solution. Also will give you more control over optimization.